# Android - How to reuse a wrapper layout for different layout XMLs?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to make every activity have a same wrapper layout like a drawer or a bottom toolbar. It's easy to create a `BaseActivity` to reuse the code for all activities. But how can I reuse the XML wrapper for all the different activity layouts **instead of adding different contents into a same XML file dynamically**?

For example, I have 5 XML layout files. They should have a same wrapper, and after I modify one of them, the others should be changed synchronously. A most simple example could be a drawer:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    // different content here

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: you can include the layout using `<include layout="@layout/mylayout"/>`

Comment: @Raghunandan But I have to copy the same wrapper for every xml in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an activity and add/remove **fragments** within it, this way the activity will hold all the common UI components and the distinct views will be in the fragments
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way that directly work on the XML? Because my layout structure is kind of complicated, I have to use nested fragments in this way,

Comment: You'll have to use the <include> layouts as @Raghunandan suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the layout separated and use  tag, and, all your activities will inherit a "BaseActivity" which will set the content, and then, in your child activity, it will find the ID for the "content", and replace it.
Does that work for you?
Note that the content may be a simple ViewGroup to be replaced.